# Vector Convolution?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution, discrete-time

I am working on a research problem which leads to the following optimization problem:
\begin{equation}
\hat{M} =\arg\max_M \|\sum_{k=0}^{M-1} {\mathbf y}_k \exp\left(-j 2\pi k \omega\right)\|^2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)
\end{equation}
where, ${\mathbf y}_k$ is a complex vector and a function of integer $k$, $\omega$ is a  real scalar (it does not change the problem if you assume that $\omega$ is some known number say one), and $M$ is an integer scalar.

The problem that I have is using discrete convolution formula, i.e. $z[n] = x[n]\star h[n] \triangleq  \sum_{k=0}^\infty x[k]h[n-k]$ to rewrite the term $\|\sum_{k=0}^{M-1} {\mathbf y}_k \exp\left(-j 2\pi k \omega\right)\|^2$ as the norm of convolution of two functions.

If ${\mathbf y}_k$ was a scalar, i.e. $y_k$, the problem would be very straightforward. We could simply use
$$\sum_{k=0}^{M-1} {y}_k \exp\left(-j 2\pi k \omega\right) = y[n]u[n]\star \exp\left(-j 2\pi n \omega\right)u[n-M+1] $$ at $n=0$, where $u[n]$ is the discrete unit step function. My question is as follows: Is there a technique to use the convolution notation to rewrite (1)?

Comment: Also on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415275/vector-convolution

Comment: Thank you for your nice and clean comment. Your solution is a very insightful and straightforward solution.  Any other insight about the problem would be useful. As you said we have different y_k s.  So may be we could envision a closed-form solution by simplifying the Convolution based reformulated formula.

Comment: it seems you meant to post this comment on the MO page? (This is one of the downsides to posting at more than one place: it is not as easy to keep track of where the conversation is!)